# Compiler Spite out Error's After Running My First Controller method

Tags: spring-mvc

I am quite new to spring mvc. I got this error the first time i ran my maven web project on window via `spring-tool-suite` for eclipse after configuring the webMVC project.

COMPILLER CONSOLE:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.buildGenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanUtils.java:354)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getNames(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:283)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:256)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.bindToSpringApplication(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:232)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:337)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
>     at com.nnokox.Application.main(Application.java:25)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Fixed formatting